# How can I enable moodle?

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, ubuntu, moodle

I've installed postgres for moodle and I got the following instructions:

> Apache/mod_php setup
>
> - Give full access to the project directory to the process running
>     apache. You might also have to set the x-flag on all .php files.
>     $ chmod -R a+rw   * Create a 'moodle.vhost.conf' from moodle.vhost.conf.example in project directory.  * Create a symlink
>     from /usr/local/var/moodle to the project directory.
>     $ cd /usr/local/var; ln -s  moodle  * Also symlink the new virtual host into apache config dir.
>     $ cd /private/etc/apache2/other
>     $ sudo ln -s /moodle.vhost.conf moodle.conf
>     $ sudo apachectl restart  * Create your own custom `/etc/vcmoodle/config_local.php` file for things local to your
>     environment by copying, and modifying if required, the example file. 
>     $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/vcmoodle
>     $ sudo cp /config_local.php.example /etc/vcmoodle/config_local.php

Still it won't work. When I look at my apache root then it comes just the standard apache page and no moodle. I've this  `sites-available`

```
:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  moodle.conf
```

and the file moodle.conf contents

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/moodle"
   ServerName moodle.localdev.kth.se

   ErrorLog /usr/local/var/moodle/error_log
   LogLevel debug

   <Directory "/usr/local/var/moodle">
     AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I don't get a moodle page at my web server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if youre running Ubuntu (judging by the tag), you need to put your project directory inside `/var/www`.  Apache cant access project folders inside your specified directory unless you change the users/groups etc.

what youve tried is the normal apache default location for web folders, but Ubuntu like to change things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate how I should put my project inside `/var/www` ?

Comment: sure. `mv -R /usr/local/var/projectdir /var/www/projectdir`